What is the translation of "pal review" in French?
pal review = peer review where peers are in fact pals, i.e. biased toward accepting the reviewed paper due to nepotism.
What is the translation of "pal review" in French?


Google Translate says: "examen d'un ami", which isn't good.
linguee.com returns no results for "pal review".


Critique de complaisance. Arrangement entre amis. Revue indulgente.

Revue critique entre {potes | poteaux | copains} pour préserver le registre d'origine.

If you mean that the review was lenient, i.e. not done with the appropriate rigour, you may translate "pal review" by révision complaisante.
Edit:
Agreeing with @None comments, the question refers to the validation of a paper, rather than a critical rereading  done by friends before submission.
I would then translate the expression by évaluation complaisante.

Plutôt revue? Je ne crois pas qu'il s'agisse d'une révision ici?

@Frank Ni révision, ni revue. A review c'est un article critique, une évaluation, on traduit habituellement peer review par « évaluation par ses pairs ».

@Frank J'allais aussi proposer évaluation quand Graffito a répondu. Pour moi révision est possible aussi, surtout si des modifications ont été apportées à un document, mais c'est surtout complaisante qui est le mot important ici. Sinon, pour review, on peut aussi suggérer relecture, tout dépend de quel type de review il s'agit (la personne elle-même ou ce qu'elle a produit).

@jlliagre Revision est aussi attesté en anglais, avec le sens de révision en français.

@Frank Révision a plusieurs sens en français.

@Frank La question est sans ambigüité : "accepting the reviewed papers", il ne s'agit pas d'une révision/relecture mais de la lecture d'un article en vue d'acception pour publication dans une revue scientifique. Il s'agit donc bien de faire du "peer-reviewing" (et non pas de "reviewing").

révision amicale
révision can be review
Pal can be translated to ami and using amicale is friendly
being a French person I would say révision amicale

Il est très clair dans la question que review n'y a pas le sens de « révision ».
